# Connection issue with AWS Redis cluster from Spring Boot App

Tags: amazon-elasticache, spring-data-redis

I am trying to integrate AWS elasticache redis with spring boot application using spring-data-redis. Getting below exception when using a service.

```
Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: Could not get a resource from the pool 
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.jedis.JedisConnectionFactory.fetchJedisConnector(JedisConnectionFactory.java:191)

... 84 more

Caused by: redis.clients.jedis.exceptions.JedisConnectionException: java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at redis.clients.jedis.Connection.connect(Connection.java:164)
```

Using below code

```
@Bean
public RedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory(JedisPoolConfig jedisPoolConfig) {
    JedisConnectionFactory redisConnectionFactory = new JedisConnectionFactory(jedisPoolConfig);
    redisConnectionFactory.setHostName("AWS primary replication group endpoint");
    redisConnectionFactory.setPort(6379);
    redisConnectionFactory.setUsePool(true);
    redisConnectionFactory.setTimeout(3600);
    return redisConnectionFactory;
}
```

I am able to connect to AWS Redis from my EC2 instance where the service is deployed. Any sample code or steps would be really helpful.

Comment: Can you successfully connect to the server using `redis-cli`?

Comment: yes i am able to connect from redis-cli

Answer (score 0):

Might be late to this party but it was my experience that declaring `spring.redis.host` in `application.yml`, `application.properties` or at the command-line as a `-D` argument were not respected by `RedisProperties` within `RedisAutoConfiguration`.

What ultimately worked for me was exporting an environment variable, like so

`export SPRING_REDIS_HOST=...`

before starting up a service that attempts to connect to ElastiCache.